# Uploading large files with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Im working on a app that generates large files (100Mb+) that I would like to upload to a web server.

By loading the file in to a NSData object that will kill the app due to memory usage (which is the only way I see in the AFNetworking docs), is there any other way to send the file together with maybe 10 other form fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't believe this question attracts so many link-only answers. Also, even with multipart form request, they will still be affected by network timeout (screen may be timed out & locked up as well). In short, all the answers at this moment are NOT the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to create an NSMutableURLRequest and set the HTTPBodyStream on it as recommended here:

http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:

I haven't tried that way but it looks like you'll probably have to assemble the multipart upload format yourself in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The above link is not found, Modified Link :

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:

Answer (score 0):

upload large file using AFNetworking you need to use

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                                   path:(NSString *)path
                                             parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> "        formData))block;
```

of `AFHttpClient`

or you can check this link for your custom implementation look for PostController :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html